# Can't get StackView to view items properly

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add 4 items to a `UIStackView`, this 4 Items are all a simple square `UIView`,  I added them all to a `UIStackView` but they won't stay square, it's like the `UIStackView` squeezes them or something. I tried setting the `UIStackView` to be the same height of the items, and set it's `width` to be the `height` of the items * 4 so I can try and get 1:1 ratio, but nothing worked for me.

The UIView is a simple `UIView` with background color. I tried to set it's `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor` to 50, but I know the `UIStackView` has it's own way to size the items in it.
I don't really know what to do about this.
This is my `UIStackView` setup and constraints:

Setup:

```
private lazy var optionButtonStack: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.optionButton1, self.optionButton2, self.optionButton3, self.optionButton4])
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.spacing = 2.5

    return stack
}()
```

Constraints:

```
private func setupOptionButtonStack() {
    addSubview(optionButtonStack)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        optionButtonStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        optionButtonStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        optionButtonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
        optionButtonStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buyNowButton.topAnchor, constant: -8),
    ])
}
```

This is the UIView in case this is needed:

```
private let optionButton1: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .appBlue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    view.tag = 1

    return view
}()
```

Comment: @matt yes, it does generate a warning because of the breaking constraints, I removed the constraints from the button, which was unnecessary to begin with, but with or without them it still does not look right. I also tried stack.alignment but that didn't help neither.

Comment: @matt which view, the uiview or the stack view? I tried giving the uiview a width and height, but I get the warning again. and when setting the stack view alignment to the center it messes it too.

Comment: @matt I did set it's height anchor and width anchor to be the same, if that what you meant, if that's not you meant I'm sorry but I didn't understood well.

Comment: @matt I'm sorry, I just got what you said, this is what I did:         view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true and of course I set the alignment of the stack view to center. this is working. THANKS! can you please tell me why this is working and setting the width and height to be equal does not? I guess it has something to do with the sizing of the stack view?

Comment: It’s because of what you said earlier. You must not contradict the constraints that the stack view itself will create. You said you wanted a square. That one constraint means “be square”. And that is all it means.

Comment: @matt thanks! just to be sure I understood it correctly, this constraints just takes the height anchor that the stack view gave the items in it and set it's width anchor to be the same. that way not matter what size the stack view will give it's items, the ratio will stay 1:1 ?

Comment: Exactly right. You are setting an aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the button view a single constraint setting its width equal to its height:

```
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

and set the stack view alignment at center.